# Credit Card payment tracking

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I want to track a user using Credit Card payment to complete an order! ( I don't use ecommerce tracking)

Is there a way to create a tag with 2 trigger condition?

1. Click trigger in Order-Form Page
2. Pageview trigger in Thank-you Page

Problem is these are not in the same page so i can't use trigger group.

the difference between cod and credit card is
COD => need to click 'order ' btn in order form
Credit => when it's succeed, automatically redirect to order_result.html

Please help!

Comment: The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have tracked the click on the CtA as an event in Order-Form Page, you can isolate sessions you want by creating a **segment** that `include` `sessions` that `contain` the `event` in Order-Form Page and the `pageview` in Thank-you Page.